# Tensorflow Loss function is NAN when using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to train custom object detection model using pre-trained model from Tensorflow1 Model ZOO.

I am using model `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29`

I created suitable environment for training following this tutorial :https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/tensorflow-1.14/training.html

The thing is, when I tried to train the model using tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0 I always got the error saying  `Model diverged with loss = NaN.`

Then I tried to uninstall `tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0` and install `tensorflow==1.14.0` (so it did not use my GPU) **and all of sudden it started to work !**

I have no idea how is that possible...

Command I am using -

`python model_main.py --alsologtostderr --model_dir=models\ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29\export --pipeline_config_path=models\ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000`

Python version is *3.7*

OS is *Windows 10*

My Graphics Card is *Nvidia GeForce RTX3050*, I used *CUDA v10.0* and *cuDNN v7.4.1*

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because RTX30's don't support cuda 10. If you need tf v1 (1.15) you can install nvidia's tensorflow (1.15) that can run on cuda 11.

`pip install nvidia-pyindex`

`pip install nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]`

Note: Only supports Python 3.6 or 3.8 [Not 3.7]

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-tensorflow-on-a100-gpus/